# Entities of an NULL character

Tags: php

How to write the `NULL` character into the text file?

I mean what's its representation in the plain text... Does it makes sense :D?
For example - in URL it would be `%00`

Answer (score 5):

NULL is ASCII 0x00

```
fwrite($fh,chr(0));
```

Comment: Can also use "\0", more useful when you're using sprintf.

Answer (score 2):

Escape sequence `\0`

```
printf("\0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite($fh, chr(0));
//or
fwrite($fh, "\0");
//or
fwrite($fh, "\x0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case but consider this example: you need to write to file array of integers, some of array members may be NULL. You write NULL as \0 (which is one byte), integers are 32 bit (4 bytes):

AA 22 BB 44 00 51 27 AF 1A ...

Now, first array member is AA 22 BB 44, second could be either NULL or 00 51 27 AF (which is valid integer value). The problem would not be solved if you used \0\0\0\0 as NULL because that's again valid integer value.

**In my opinion it would be better, if you used serialization.**

Comment: If you have issues with writing numeric values as binary, then you need to use pack() http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php paying particular heed to the "caution" in the documentation

Comment: I don't think that pack() would help in this particular case. pack() needs fixed format, there's none in this case. There's simply no way you can represent NULL in 32bit integer. Notice how this problem is solved e.g. in MySQL. 32bit integer is actually 33bit, the last bit is used to represent NULL value. So you'd need to do something similar for pack(), but not for serialize(). pack() is better only if output size matters.